# Visualforce page not appearing in Dashboard data sources list

Tags: dashboard

I tried to use some of my visualforce pages as Dashboard component but did not see those pages in Data Sources list in Dashboard. Am i missing something? Do the visualforce page should have some qualities to appear in Data Sources for dashboard or to be used as Dashboard component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the documentation ([which you can find here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_basic_dashboard_components.htm)) the Visualforce page must meet the following criteria to appear in the list of available components.

> Visualforce pages that use the Standard Controller can’t be used in
>   dashboards. To be included in a dashboard, a Visualforce page must
>   have either no controller, use a custom controller, or reference a
>   page bound to the StandardSetController Class. If a Visualforce page
>   does not meet these requirements, it does not appear as an option in
>   the dashboard component Visualforce Page drop-down list.